# Google Sheet Retune Row Between Column Match Value in Google sheet script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The employee sheet contains the id of the employee in Column `B`. image may help to understand how this code should be work.

How can I get the rows matches the employee id?

I tried the following script and more but it doesn't seem to work.

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d28cE.png)

```
function getTwoVal() {

  var idUrl = "idi";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idUrl).getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()

   var filteredRows = data.filter(function (row) {
     if (row[5] === '102' || row[5] === '106') {
       return row;
     }
   });

  console.log(filteredRows )

}
```

Comment: From your provided image and `getValues()`, I thought that the column "B" of the retrieved values might be the number type. If my understanding is correct, in your situation, when `if (row[5] === '102' || row[5] === '106') {` is modified to `if (row[1] >= 102 && row[1] <= 106) {`, is that the result you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
   var filteredRows = data.filter(function (row) {
     if (row[1] == '102' || row[1] == '106') {
       return row;
     }
   });
```

if id is in column B, use `row[1]` instead of `row[5]`

if id may be numeric, use `==` instead of `===`

or, if you want between as the title suggests

```
   var filteredRows = data.filter(function (row) {
     if (row[1] >= 102 && row[1] <= 106) {
       return row;
     }
   });
```

Comment: Numbers work fine thanks - If everything is the same but data is a string like this start 12_03_2022 to end18_03_2022 this is not a date regular string, how can I handle this any reference sir.

Comment: You will need to transform in yyyymdd for instance. Write the if statement as `if (row[1].substring(6,10)+row[1].substring(3,5)+row[1].substring(0,2) == '20220312' || row[1].substring(6,10)+row[1].substring(3,5)+row[1].substring(0,2) == '20220318')`or `if (row[1].substring(6,10)+row[1].substring(3,5)+row[1].substring(0,2) >= '20220312' && row[1].substring(6,10)+row[1].substring(3,5)+row[1].substring(0,2) <= '20220318')`